npm run build が上手くいかない
laravel sail,vue3,inertiaの技術選定でローカルの npm run dev では動くのですが、npm run build した際に以下のようなエラーが発生して進めません。解決策をご教授頂けますと幸いです。
error during build:
[vite:vue] [plugin vite:vue] resources/js/Pages/Welcome.vue: At least one `<template>` or `<script>` is required in a single file component.
file: /var/www/html/resources/js/Pages/Welcome.vue
SyntaxError: At least one <template> or <script> is required in a single file component.
    at Object.parse$2 [as parse] (/var/www/html/node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:1923:7)
    at createDescriptor (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue/dist/index.mjs:64:43)
    at transformMain (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue/dist/index.mjs:2376:34)
    at Object.transform (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue/dist/index.mjs:2919:16)
    at file:///var/www/html/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:19774:40

vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import Icons from 'unplugin-icons/vite'
import { FileSystemIconLoader } from 'unplugin-icons/loaders'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
        // プラグインのunplugin-icons用加筆
        Icons({
            customCollections: {
                svg: FileSystemIconLoader('src/assets/icons')
            },
        }),
    ],
});

package.json
{
"private": true,
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@inertiajs/vue3": "^1.1.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.5",
    "alpinejs": "^3.4.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "axios": "^1.6.4",
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
    "unplugin-icons": "^0.19.0",
    "vite": "^5.0",
    "vue": "^3.4.27"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.6.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.2"
}

}

エラーログを見たところ resources/js/Pages/Welcome.vue ファイルに <template> か <script> タグが無いようです。
[vite:vue] [plugin vite:vue] resources/js/Pages/Welcome.vue: At least one `<template>` or `<script>` is required in a single file component.

Welcome.vue の変更分を差し戻すか、buildできるように変更する必要があります。
